# Mark externally-declared bean as @Primary

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app that requires multiple datasources that will be used via JdbcTemplates to make sql statements to different DBs.  These datasource beans are already declared in external dependencies that I am pulling into my app via an @Import statement the JdbcTemplate-bean-declaring java-based @Configuration classes.

After declaring two different JdbcTemplates initialized with two different DataSource beans form these external dependencies, I run into the following error on app startup:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
```

Given that I don't have access to the declarations of these DataSource beans in my app, how can I mark one as @Primary?

EDIT: Here's code for the construction of the JdbcTemplates (Note "`dataSourceA`" and "`dataSourceB`" are pulled from an external dependency)

```
@Configuration
@Import({DataSourceAApplicationConfig.class, DataSourceBApplicationConfig.class})
public class    JdbcTemplateAppConfig {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSourceA;
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSourceB;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateForDataSourceA(@Qualifier("dataSourceA") DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateForDataSourceB@Qualifier("dataSourceB") DataSource dataSource){
        JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        return template;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show code here? From the question possibly looks code smell.

Comment: Could we see the configurations you're importing as well?  I *think* what you want to accomplish is possible but it doesn't have to involve making the data sources themselves primary.